# Как создать инсталлятор для настройки VSTO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office, vsto

У меня стоит `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017`. Необходимо создать инсталлятор для созданной `настройки VSTO для PowerPoint 2013`.

В Интернете все ссылки в основном ведут сюда [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx), в которой сказано, что есть два пути создания установщика:

1. `ClickOnce`. Я сделал по такому способу, там все сводилось публикацией как мы это делаем в ASP.NET. Но такой setup.exe через пару шагов сообщает что манифест приложения (плагина) не подписан, и установка останавливается. В одном из чатов коллега сказал, что можно и без подписи, просто будет светится "неизвестный издатель", но я так и не понял, как это сделать.
2. Но мне хотелось бы создать инсталятор вот по второму пути - с помощью так
   называемого `InstallShield Limited Edition`. Я нигде у себя в
   "менюшках" не могу его найти.

Подскажите как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По какой-то причине Microsoft не включила шаблоны проектов инсталлятора в поставку Visual Studio 2017 по умолчанию. Но их легко установить с официального сайта.

Для этого вы заходите в Tools → Extensions and Updates → Online → Visual Studio Marketplace, при помощи поиска находите там пакет Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects, и устанавливаете его:

[image: who installs the installer?]

После этого вам станут доступны проекты инсталлятора:

[image: installer successfully installed]

Comment: Отлично! Значит я на правильном пути, т.к. уже установил `Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects`, но думал что это совсем другое. Теперь, нет никакой документации как с помощью этого `VS 2017 Installer Projects` сделать инсталлятор для моего плагина. Может ссылкой на какой-то туториал можете поделиться?

Comment: @adamshakhabov: К сожалению, я сам никогда не пользовался, так что туториалов не знаю.